# VBA for Web Scraping works as Sub but Not as Function

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have written a VBA to scrape the status of a shipment from a cargo tracking site with the help of you guys here. I am trying to convert it to a function. The code works as a sub but does not work as a function. It returns a #Value error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code as a sub

```
Sub FlightStat_AFL()
    
    Dim url As String
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim MAWBStatus As String
    Dim MAWBNo As String
    
    MAWBNo = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H3").Value
    
      'You can handle the parameters id and pfx in a loop to scrape dynamic numbers
      url = "https://www.afklcargo.com/mycargo/shipment/detail/057-" & MAWBNo
      
      
      'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
      'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
      Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      ie.Visible = False
      ie.navigate url
      Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
      
      'Wait to load dynamic content after IE reports it's ready
      'We do that with a fix manual break of a few seconds
      'because the whole page will be "reload"
      'The last three values are hours, minutes, seconds
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
      
      'Get the status from the table
     MAWBStatus = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("fs-12 body-font-bold")(1).innertext
      
      Debug.Print MAWBStatus
      
      'Clean up
      ie.Quit
      Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the code I am trying to make it work as a function.

```
Function FlightStat_AF(MAWBNo As Range) As String
    
    Dim url As String
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim MAWBStatus As String

    url = "https://www.afklcargo.com/mycargo/shipment/detail/057-" & MAWBNo
    
      'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
      'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
      Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      ie.Visible = False
      ie.navigate url
      Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
      
      'Wait to load dynamic content after IE reports it's ready
      'We do that with a fix manual break of a few seconds
      'because the whole page will be "reload"
      'The last three values are hours, minutes, seconds
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
      
      'Get the status from the table
      MAWBStatus = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("fs-12 body-font-bold")(1).innertext
      FlightStat_AF = MAWBStatus
      
      'Clean up
      ie.Quit
      Set ie = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: In your function `FlightStat_AF` the variable `url` is empty when you `ie.navigate url`. It does not navigate anywhere. Therefore it only can error. • You need to set a URL for that variable first before navigating.

Comment: Should `MAWBNo` Range keep the `url`? If yes, your code does not use it at all and you should use `url = MAWBNo.Value`. If not, how do you intend to pass the `url` and why do you try using that range like a function argument?

Comment: Sorry @Pᴇʜ. Modified the code. But still gives an #Value error.

Comment: @FaneDuru. Sorry. I have modified the code. But still gives a #Value error.

Comment: On which line, please?

Comment: @FaneDuru, Line 5. after the dims have been declared.

Comment: Are you passing the correct range to the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221094/discussion-between-achal-desai-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Function FlightStat_AF(cargoNo As Variant) As String
 Dim url As String, ie As Object, result As String

  url = "https://www.afklcargo.com/mycargo/shipment/detail/" & cargoNo

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  With ie
    .Visible = False
    .navigate url
    Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  End With
  'wait a little for dynamic content to be loaded
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))

  'Get the status from the table
  Do While result = ""
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
     result = Trim(ie.document.getElementsByClassName("fs-12 body-font-bold")(1).innerText)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
  Loop

  ie.Quit: Set ie = Nothing
  
  'Return value of the function
  FlightStat_AF = result
End Function
```

Comment: @Achal Desai: Glad i could help! I must confess that I did not imagine that a UDF function could have such a behavior...

Answer (score 0):

### IE Function

- You can try this if you really want a range. Usually it should be a string which you can easily change.
- You can test the function (2nd procedure) with the first procedure. Just adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub getFlightStat()
    
    ' Constants
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 3
    Const CritCol As Variant = "H"
    Const ResCol As Variant = "I"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Calculate the row of the last non-blank cell in column 'CritCol'.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, CritCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through rows and for each value in cell of column 'CritCol',
    ' write the value retrieved via 'FlightStat_AF' to the cell
    ' in the same row, but in column 'ResCol'.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        ws.Cells(i, ResCol).Value = FlightStat_AF(ws.Cells(i, CritCol))
    Next i
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

Function FlightStat_AF(MAWBNo As Range) As String
    
    Dim url As String
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim MAWBStatus As String
    
    'You can handle the parameters id and pfx in a loop to scrape dynamic numbers
    url = "https://www.afklcargo.com/mycargo/shipment/detail/057-" & MAWBNo.Value
    
    'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
    'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate url
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    'Wait to load dynamic content after IE reports it's ready
    'We do that with a fix manual break of a few seconds
    'because the whole page will be "reload"
    'The last three values are hours, minutes, seconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
    
    'Get the status from the table
    MAWBStatus = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("fs-12 body-font-bold")(1).innertext
    FlightStat_AF = MAWBStatus
    
    'Clean up
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I am referencing a cell which will have the MAWB no in it. Since I am referring to a cell, I used As Range argument. Would it still work if I refer to a cell but dim it As String?

Comment: Of course, just in the `ws.Cells` line of the test procedure add `.Value` or not, and remove `.Value` in the Function

Comment: I tried the sub and it worked. But if used only as a function, it still gives me a #Value.